# ios tableview does not scroll up when action sheet is dismissed

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikeyboard

I am developing an chat app, i have used tableview to display the messages sent and receive and a view with textfield and add button at the bottom.
On clicking add button action sheet is displayed with options
Everything works fine except, when i click on add button and tap cancel button of action sheet and then tap on textfield....tableview does not scroll up when keyboard is shown

[image]

Below is the code for keyboardwillshow notification

KeyboardWillShow :

```
NSValue *keyboardBoundsValue = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey];
    NSValue *keyboardBoundsValue = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey];

    CGRect keyboardBounds;
    [keyboardBoundsValue getValue:&keyboardBounds];
    NSNumber *duration = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey];
    NSNumber *curve = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey];

    // Need to translate the bounds to account for rotation.
    keyboardBounds = [self.view convertRect:keyboardBounds toView:nil];

    CGRect containerFrame = viewDummy.frame;// viewDummy is the view where keyboard, add button and speak button is displayed
    containerFrame.origin.y = self.view.bounds.size.height - (keyboardBounds.size.height + containerFrame.size.height);
    NSLayoutConstraint *constPaddingwithViewTable.constant = keyboardBounds.size.height + containerFrame.size.height;

    // animations settings
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:[duration doubleValue]];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:[curve intValue]];

    // set views with new info
    viewDummy.frame = containerFrame;


    // commit animations
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to have been some good questions and answers on this before.

The following seems particularly good: [How to make a UITextField move up when keyboard is present?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present)

This also references the Apple docs on the subject of keyboard and content scrolling. It includes a fix for their example code. [Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW7)

Answer (score -1):

Add this below setting your constraint 
`[self.view layoutIfNeeded];`